# Adopting NSTextFinderBarContainer protocol in Swift forces variable initialization despite header comment

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I have an `NSView` subclass that implements the `NSTextFinderBarContainer` protocol. Part of the `NSTextFinderBarContainer` protocol is implementing

```
var findBarView: NSView { get set }
```

However the comment above this property in the original Objective-C header is:

> This property is used by NSTextFinder to assign a find bar to a
>   container. The container may freely modify the view's width, but
>   should not modify its height. This property is managed by
>   NSTextFinder. **You should not set this property.**

Because Swift requires all instance variables to be initialized, how do I handle this situation? It appears Swift requires me to go against what Apple has wrote in the header: you should not set this property as it will be set/managed by the `NSTextFinder` itself.

If I don't override the NSView initializers I get:

> Class 'ExampleContainerView' has no initializers

As expected since `findBarView` does not have an initial value.

The relevant parts of my Swift code are:

```
class ExampleContainerView: NSView, NSTextFinderBarContainer {

    var findBarView : NSView

    ...
}
```

If I override the designated initializer to initialize `findBarView` as follows (ignoring Apple's comment in the header):

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    findBarView = NSView(frame: NSRect())
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

The app crashes after the NSTextFinder is sent the `setFindBarContainer:` message

> -[NSView _setTextFinder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000001278a0

The object at **0x6000001278a0** is the NSView instance set in the overridden initializer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears fixed as of Xcode 7.0 beta 6. `NSTextFinderBarContainer` now declares `findBarView` as an optional `NSView`:

`public var findBarView: NSView? { get set }`

In addition, `contentView()` also changed to return an optional `NSView`:

`optional public func contentView() -> NSView?`

Making the property optional means there is no longer the contradiction of having the API comments say not to set `findBarView`, while having Swift require that all non-optional properties are initialized in in your initializers.